# ELSA Workflow vs Durable Task Framework

Tags: elsa-workflows

My current understanding is that Durable Task Framework (https://github.com/Azure/durabletask) is the building block used by Azure Durable Functions to implement business orchestration (workflows).   I am just curious if anyone has compared this framework with Elsa, and if they are more or less solving the same problem ?

As a beginner, just starting, I get the sense that Elsa has higher level abstractions making its API a bit more fluent and readable, where as DTF has more primitive abstractions and reads more like C# code

Any clarifications or thoughts welcome !

Answer (score 1):

According to this:
https://github.com/elsa-workflows/elsa-core#what-about-azure-logic-apps

> As powerful and as complete Azure Logic Apps is, it's available only
> as a managed service in Azure. Elsa on the other hand allows you to
> host it not only on Azure, but on any cloud provider that supports
> .NET Core. And of course you can host it on-premise.
>
> Although you can implement long-running workflows with Logic Apps, you
> would typically do so with splitting your workflow with multiple Logic
> Apps where one workflow invokes the other. This can make the logic
> flow a bit hard to follow. with Elsa, you simply add triggers anywhere
> in the workflow, making it easier to have a complete view of your
> application logic. And if you want, you can still invoke other
> workflows form one workflow.